# Processes spawning randomly and sucking CPU

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process

I am currently on Ubuntu 16.04, and I have noticed slowdowns across the server in general. Upon viewing `htop`, I noticed that processes with random commands are spawning, while taking the CPU usage with it; [Here is the image that shows an offending process.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4qCG.png) When trying to view which user started the process, the pts shows as a '?' as shown below:

```
# ps -feww | grep netstat
root      7444     1 91 01:29 ?        00:01:37 netstat -antop
root     13051     1  0 01:31 ?        00:00:00 netstat -antop
root     13063     1  0 01:31 ?        00:00:00 netstat -antop
```

I successfully killed the process with signal 9, but after a few seconds, another process with a completely different command pops up, and ran until I killed it. Rebooting the server did not fix this.

Would appreciate some advice on this, thanks!

Comment: What are the `completely different command`s?

Comment: The commands really show no resemblance. I've noticed ls grep and pwd off the top of my head

Comment: Have you tried running `who` and ensuring that everyone that is listed in expected?

Comment: Your server could be compromised. Read http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server for information on how to deal with it.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen was right, I found a suspicious file on /bin, XorDos rootkit, resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the server was compromised from XorDos, causing it to run random process while doing a spoofed UDP flood.

Comment: I hope you have re-installed the system from backups, since deleting one file doesn't resolve anything.

Comment: Did a full wipe and reinstall so its gone in the wind

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution

https://admin-ahead.com/forum/server-security-hardening/unix-trojan-ddos_xor-1-chinese-chicken-multiplatform-dos-botnets-trojan/

so your virus is in /lib/libudev.so or /lib/libudev4.so

you need to 
chattr -i /lib/libudev.so 
then remove,reboot and then delete all other crap (check URL above)

you can install ClamAV for linux 
https://www.centosblog.com/how-to-install-clamav-and-configure-daily-scanning-on-centos/